# Is it possible to create a cmd script that prevents users from deleting a file located in the desktop?

Tags: cmd, admin

I want to create a cmd script that will prevent users from deleting a file, giving them a message that you need to enter the admin password to delete this.

- I want to apply this cmd script on a batch file, as well as a zip file

  I have got this type of message before

  I need the script to be undeletable too.

Thank you! 
Sorry if I am a bit unspecific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a security question not programming. Set *Read and Execute* only on the two files for whichever users and *Deny* for everything else on Everybody. Right click, Properties, Security ...